# Save only cell value of DataGridView as an image

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying below:

```cs
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap ssp = new Bitmap(dataGridView1.Width, dataGridView1.Height);
    dataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(ssp, new Rectangle(0, 0, dataGridView1.Width, dataGridView1.Height));

    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "PNG Image File|*.png";
    saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save PNG Screenshot";
    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        ssp.Save(saveFileDialog1.FileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Pattern Files|*.sat";
    saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save Pattern File";
    saveFileDialog1.FileName = "";
}
```

The result is below image:

[image: Result]

But actually I want to save only area portion which is draw like chess not whole DataGridView image.

Need like below image:

[image: Need]

Comment: You could try this trick: Grab the cell bounds when it is painted: `Rectangle cellrectxy = Rectangle.Empty;
private void dgv_filters_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.RowIndex == 1) cellrectxy = e.CellBounds;
}` Use you own numbers, of course..!

Comment: thanks for reply,actually  i want to save only that area like same as second image.

Comment: Please consider adding `winforms` tag to the question.

Comment: I answered to the title. But you can easily expand the trick to get the top left and the bottom right coordinates.

Comment: Why would you draw that Cell's content when you can take the Image from the `DataGridViewImageCell`? Does the DGV belong to another app? Is the Image painted? In any case, how are  determining which is the *right* Cell? Is it the only one showing a Bitmap?